# Are autoencoders computationally cheaper than MLPs with the same number of neurons?

Tags: comparison, autoencoders, multilayer-perceptrons, computational-complexity, time-complexity

Are autoencoders computationally cheaper than other neural networks such as MLP with the same number of neurons?

I have read in some papers that autoencoders train the network faster, and I could check it in python, the training part is faster than a MLP. However, all these papers mention it briefly. However, I could not find an accurate explanation for this. Do you know why this happened?

Comment: Could you link the papers that you are talking about? I do not have enough information/context to understand the question at the moment

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The papers that I have read are https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002002552100462X (page 13) and https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020025517309659 (page 2)